# Sencha Cmd 3.0.0.250 : Response file (sencha @file) error

Tags: extjs, compiler-construction, command

I get an error using Sencha Command via a "response file" named "compile.sencha". Here is the content of this file :

```
compile
    -cl=ext/src
page
    -in Page1.php
    -out build/Page1.php and
page
    -in Page2.php
    -out build/Page2.php
```

To execute these commands I call the file in the Windows command prompt as it is explained in the [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/command_advanced) :

```
sencha @compile.sencha
```

Here is the output :

```
[ERR] Only expected 1 parameter
```

The problem does not occur when I type directly in the command prompt but it's a painful solution... Hope anyone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself using a batch file and `^` as linebreaks.